# Need help on picking a right type of p channel mosfet to light up an LED (as per attached schematic)

Tags: analog

[image]

HI All,

Can you help me to chose a p channel MOSFET that can do the job of turning On/Off the LED with an input from VSF6 which toggles between 0 & 1.8V? Appreciate all the technical gurus help.

Comment: Is Vcc 450 volts?

Comment: *input from VSF6 which toggles between 0 & 1.8V?* Then this schematic is not going to work. The high value (LED off) of VSF6 will have to switch to the value of VCC to make the PMOS switch off completely. If you would make Vcc= 1.8 V (so that the PMOS does turn off properly) then the Yellow LED can never light up as it needs a higher voltage to work.